# PowerBI Dax Column for Dynamic Top N + Others

Tags: dynamic, powerbi, dax, greatest-n-per-group, rank

I have the following columns and measures:

Columns

- dimension
- entity

Measures

- CountOrder
- DynamicRank - identify the top N entity based on CountOrder per Dimension.
- TopNEntity - if DynamicRank is blank then "Others" else Entity

Issue: I am trying to convert the TopNEntity into a column in Dax. When I try to create a column, each row shows "Other" vs. the entity like in the Top N Entity Measure.

Here is my equation:`DyanmicRank =`  IF (ISINSCOPE ('Dimension Slicer'[Entity]),VAR ProductsToRank = 'Parameter'[Parameter Value]
VAR SalesAmount = [Count Order Dimension Slicer] RETURN IF (SalesAmount > 0,
VAR VisibleProducts = CALCULATETABLE (VALUES ('Dimension Slicer'[Entity]),          ALLSELECTED ('Dimension Slicer'[Entity]))
VAR Ranking = RANKX ( VisibleProducts, [Count Order Dimension Slicer], , DESC, Dense)
RETURN IF (Ranking > 0 && Ranking <= ProductsToRank, Ranking, BLANK())))`